# Displaying 2 models in a view from join query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to display a joined query results in my view but I keep getting this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`2[MvcFFL.Models.TmPlyrs,MvcFFL.Models.Player]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcFFL.Models.TmPlyrs]'

here is the query that is being returned from the controller:

```
var z = (from y in db.Teamplayers
                join p in db.Players on y.playerid equals p.Nid
                select new { y, p }).ToList();

        return View(z);
```

Now here is how my view looks that the data is being returned to:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcFFL.Models.TmPlyrs>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TeamPlayers", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <text>Team </text>@Html.DropDownList("Tms", "All")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.playerid)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.teamid)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.playerid
        </td>
        <td>
           @item.teamid
       </td>
       <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
       </td>
   </tr>
}

</table>
```

How can i make it return the results without the error?

Comment: you have to create a view model

Comment: i think instead of doing @model IEnumerable<MvcFFL.Models.TmPlyrs> you need to replace IEnumerable<T> with IEnumerable<dynamic>. I sugegst you just create a view model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass two model objects to the view as your view is binded to only one Model class, so what you need is to create a View Model class which will have properties of both classes.

Suppose your models are like this:

```
public class TeamPlayers
{

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Name {get;set;}
    public int Nid {get;set;}
    ..........................
    ..........................

}


public class Player
{

public int PlayerId {get;set;}
public int PlayerName {get;set;}
................................
................................
}
```

Cretae a folder in your project with name **ViewModels** and make a ViewModel which has properties of both models:

```
public class TeamPlayersViewModel
{

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Nid {get;set;}
    public int PlayerIdId {get;set;}
    public string PlayerName {get;set;}
    ...................................
    ...................................
}
```

Now your linq query:

```
var z = (from y in db.Teamplayers
         join p in db.Players on y.playerid equals p.Nid
         select new TeamPlayersViewModel{
         Id= y.Id,
         PlayerName = p.PlayerName,
         ..........................
         .......................... }).ToList<TeamPlayersViewModel>();
```

Now in your view change model:

```
@model List<MvcFFL.ViewModels.TeamPlayersViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<h2>Index</h2>
```

Comment: i was also too stucked when first time i needed to passing two models to view but we learn by time glad it helped...:)

Answer (score 0):

first of all create a new model

```
class MyModel{
   Teamplayers team{get; set;}
   Players players{get; set;}
}
```

set in the view the type of model as `MyModel`

then

```
var z = (from y in db.Teamplayers
                join p in db.Players on y.playerid equals p.Nid
                select new MyModel { team=y, players=p }).ToList();

        return View(z);
```